# Rails SQLite3::SQLException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm new at the Rails framework and following Michael Hartl's tutorials. The error I have currently is below: [image]

First of all I see it says `no such column: users.remember_token` but why? Because I run this code:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

Before which I have a file with content:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

I am suspecting that this my come from my `db/development.sqlite3` because I actually don't see a `remember_token` column. But my assumption was after running `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate` I should see the new column right? This is how the `development.sqlite3` looks like:

[image]

I also have a SessionsHelper file which looks like this:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
end
```

Comment: I must ask if your migration is in the migration folder, db/migrate, and if it has a name with a datetime stamp in it. Then, does your `schema_migrations` table contain this datetime stamp? That's what rake db:migrate checks to determine if it should migrate. The fix is to erase your development.sqlite3 file and start again.

Comment: Do you have the `rake db:migrate` command output? If not, try `rake db:drop db:create` and then `rake db:migrate` again. WARNING: this will erase all your data. If you don't mind, go ahead.

Comment: terffic! i'm up again. Thanks: @Phlip and Andre.

Comment: Another handy rake command to see your migration status: `bundle exec rake db:migrate:status` which will let you know the status of all migrations... Likely your migration was failing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Per Andre: `rake db:drop db:create rake db:migrate`. WARNING: this will erase all your data.

Per me: Read your `schema_migrations` table to see if db:migrate with think it should run your migration...

Answer (score 0):

@Phlip 's answer worked for me.
when you database already have some user, then "remember_token" migrate won't work. you must clean your date firt,then do db:migrate.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact issue. Carbon copy of this question. Even after following the directions in the accepted answer, I could not get the "remember_token" column to be added to the database even though the migration file was there inside db/migrate. I opened the actual migration file and noticed that it did not contain everything needed. My migration file looked like this:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
end
```

When it needed to be this:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
  add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

After adding in the missing code, saving, then doing a db:migrate, I was back in business!
Just wanted to leave this here, if someone else runs into the same issue.